# Operator precedence in a find command?

Tags: find

See below example:

```
$ ls -1p
appledir/
applefile
orangedir/
orangefile
$ find . -type f -name apple\*
./applefile
$ find . -type f -name orange\*
./orangefile
$ find . -type f -name apple\* -o -name orange\*
./applefile
./orangedir
./orangefile
$ find . -type f \( -name apple\* -o -name orange\* \)
./applefile
./orangefile
$
```

I was surprised to discover I needed the parentheses for this to work as expected; apparently I haven't internalized the rule of precedence by which `find` evaluates its arguments.

How can I easily predict when I will and when I will not need to use parentheses to explicitly group `find` primaries?

Put another way, what are the rules by which I can imagine `find` *inserting* parentheses into the commands I give it, which will allow me to accurately predict how it will evaluate ungrouped expressions?

Comment: Related: [`find` with multiple `-name` and `-exec` executes only the last matches of `-name`](/q/102191)

Comment: Thanks, @StéphaneChazelas; that is indeed a *much* more complete discussion and answer to this same question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html),

> Please note that `-a` when specified implicitly (for example by two
>          tests appearing without an explicit operator between them) or
>          explicitly has higher precedence than `-o`.  This means that `find . -name afile -o -name bfile -print` will never print `afile`.

So basically you can imagine `find` surrounding any two "anded" expressions with parentheses by default. Your

```
find . -type f -name apple\* -o -name orange\*
```

is interpreted as

```
find . \( -type f -name apple\* \) -o -name orange\*
```

Comment: does this mean that find doesn't distinguish between `test` or `action` tokens? and simply looks at whether the operand evaluates `true` or `false` in the same way `test` would in a shell script?

Comment: @the_velour_fog that's right; in fact actions also return true or false depending on whether they succeed.

Comment: ah thats what I struggled to understand, I always assumed that `find` would have treated `test` and `action` primaries differently, the way a compiler would recognise and treat variable types like array, int and string differently. but you really need to treat `find` like its a little programming language and manage the operators and operands yourself, thanks

Comment: @the_velour_fog, from [Unix Power Tools, 3rd Edition](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch17_12.htm): *"`find`'s business is evaluating expressions - not locating files. Yes, `find` certainly locates files; but that's really just a side effect. For me, understanding this point was the conceptual breakthrough that made `find` much more useful."*

Comment: @wildcard, yes getting that its really a conditional expression evaluator  is important. as per your question - and my challenge - was *how* do the rules work. comparing the find command to a shell conditional expression (although much more complicated than normal) is what my breakthrough was with find. It also helped with my general programming too.