# Are parentheses required to be backslashed to specify precedence in find commands?

Tags: find

In this command

```
find . -xdev -type f \( -mtime 0 -or -mtime 1 \) -exec cp -aPv "{}" $dest.new \;
```

Do the parentheses in `\( -mtime 0 -or -mtime 1 \)` mean precedence?

Are they required to be preceded by backslash? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the parentheses mean precedence, and the backslashes are required to escape them for the shell. From `man find`.

```
   ( expr )
          Force  precedence.   Since  parentheses  are special to the shell, you will normally need to quote them.  Many of the examples in this manual page use backslashes for this purpose: `\(...\)'
          instead of `(...)'.
```

So in your example, they are just to group the `-or` statement. There's more information [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276574/operator-precedence-in-a-find-command?rq=1) on order of precedence.

Comment: Thanks. If not escaped, how does the shell interpret the parentheses?

Comment: @Tim you could just try it yourself...

Comment: @Tim The parentheses just get directly interpreted by the shell. Most (all?) of the time the shell would spawns a subshell, which would break your `find` command. That's how it works in bash, zsh, etc. at least…

Comment: @Sparhawk most of the time it results in a syntax error; the shell doesn't spawn a subshell, it tries to parse the command and stops at the unexpected `(`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, I meant that the shell (probably) *interprets* it as a command to spawn a subshell, and fails because the line is just… wrong.