# find files satisfying both requirements simultaneously

Tags: find

I have never before needed to use `find` with multiple search terms. I found this:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*foo*" -o -name "*bar*" \)
```

..but it finds files which satisfy either of them, not both simultaneously.

Does anyone know how to adjust it so it finds files which simultaneously meet both requirements?

I try to avoid regex so would be nicer if it can be done without, but if not, as long as it works.

Comment: so, given a list of some files, e.g. `foo.pl`, `bar.pl`, `foo.pm`, `asdf.pm`, and `hello.txt`, which one(s) would you like to find? Obviously none them match _both_ the patterns at the same time, because that's impossible, both patterns look at the ending of the filename, and there can only be one set of letters there.

Comment: Sorry about that I fixed it. I wasn't even looking for endings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent for logical AND is `-a`. However, logical AND is the default anyhow, as the manual notes:

```
  Operators
          Operators  join  together  the other items within the expression.  
          They include for example -o (meaning logical OR) and -a (meaning logical AND).  
          Where an operator is missing, -a is assumed.
```

So you can simply chain the conditions like

```
find [paths] condition1 condition2 ...
```

ex.

```
find . -type f -name "*foo*" -name "*bar*"
```

In fact that's what you're implicitly doing with

```
find . -type f \( -name "*foo*" -o -name "*bar*" \)
```

which could have been written

```
find . -type f -a \( -name "*foo*" -o -name "*bar*" \)
```

Note that the parentheses are required in the `-o` case because of operator precedence with the default `-print` action; without parentheses it would look like

```
find . \( -type f -a -name "*foo*" \) -o \( -name "*bar*" -a -print \)
```

(which would only print entries matching `-name "*bar*"`, and do so regardless of their type) - in the `-a` case, all the tests bind with the same precedence and parentheses are not necessary. See for example [Operator precedence in a find command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276574/operator-precedence-in-a-find-command)