# find subdirectories from different mount points without symlinks that have the same name as the subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find

I struggle to find a working `find` command, I hope someone has an idea. Imagine the following structure, where path and path{0..1} exist and they are each mounted from a network storage device:

```
dir:  /path/userA
link: /path/userB -> /path2/userB

dir: /path1/userA

dir: /path2/userB
```

My expected result is:

```
/path/userA
/path1/userA
/path2/userB
```

The `find` command should look something like this:

```
find /path /path{0..9} -maxdepth 1 -type d -name userA -o -name userB
```

Unfortunately no matter how I tweak and twist the command, either less directories than the expected are shown or still all four... find seems to always follow the symlinks.

I've tried `-P` , `-H`, `-L` options, tried "`! -type l`" and various combinations, tried -exec  addidtions like "`-exec test -d {} \; -print`", none of them giving the expected result.

Interestingly, if I try to find only the symlink, find still follows it and print the referenced directory:

```
find /path /path{0..9} -maxdepth 1 -type l -name userA -o -name userB
/path/userB
/path2/userB
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try changing `-name userA -o -name userB` to `\( -name userA -o -name userB \)`.

Comment: No way, this really works! Could you explain the reason for this?

Comment: The [answer to the linked duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276575/108618) should do. If not, there's a good link under the question there and many linked questions in the right column, some with answers. And [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1387985/432690) on Super User.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: just iterate on each path you want to test: put them (one by line) in /path/to/list_of_path_to_test; and then do : `while IFS= read -r pathtotest; do cd -P thispath && pwd >> /path/to/the_list; done < /path/to/list_of_path_to_test ; sort /path/to/the_list | uniq` # cd -P will print the "canonical" path not the symlink-based one